# covering map with finite fibres and preimage of a compact set

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a covering map (covering maps are surjective) , Y be compact set. And suppose that $f^{-1}(y) $ is finite for each $y\in Y$. Prove that $X$ is also compact.

I think that this problem does not need the hyphotesis of covering map , I think that only is necessary that $f$ is an open map (covering maps are open maps)

Well I dunno how to start this problem :/

If I consider an open covering $ X = \bigcup U_a $ , then $f(X)=Y = f(\bigcup U_a) = \bigcup f(U_a) $

I don't know if it's convenient to consider a finite subcovering of $Y$ at this moment, or I need some tricky argument ... Please help me )=

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do need more than the fact that the map is open and has finite fibres and compact range.

For $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ let $$X_n=\left\{\left\langle\frac1n,k\right\rangle\in\Bbb R\times\Bbb Z:0\le k\le n\right\}\;,$$ and let $$X=\{\langle0,0\rangle\}\cup\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}X_n\;,$$ topologized as a subset of $\Bbb R^2$ with the usual topology. Let $f:X\to\Bbb R:\langle x,y\rangle\mapsto x$ be the projection to the first coordinate, and let

$$Y=f[X]=\{0\}\cup\left\{\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}\;;$$

clearly $Y$ is compact, and $f$ has finite fibres. I claim that $f$ is open.

To see this, let $U\subseteq X$ be open. If $\langle0,0\rangle\notin U$, then $f[U]\subseteq Y\setminus\{0\}$, so $f[U]$ is open in $Y$. And if $\langle0,0\rangle\in U$, there is an $m\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $\left\langle\frac1n,0\right\rangle\in U$ for each $n\ge m$, in which case $f[U]$ contains a nbhd of $0$ in $Y$ and must again be open in $Y$.

Finally, $X$ is clearly not compact, as $\left\{\left\langle\frac1n,n\right\rangle:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}$ is a closed set in $X$ with no limit point.

Notice that this $f$ is not a covering map: the point $0$ in $Y$ has no evenly covered open nbhd. You really will need to use the fact that you’re dealing with a covering map.

**Added:** A map $f:X\to Y$ is *perfect* if it is continuous and closed and has compact fibres. If you prove that your covering map is closed, you’ll have shown that it is perfect. Now use the following lemma.

> **Lemma.** If $f:X\to Y$ is perfect, and $Y$ is compact, then $X$ is compact.
>
> **Start of Proof.** Let $\mathscr{U}$ be an open cover of $X$. For each $y\in Y$ let $X_y=f^{-1}\big[\{y\}\big]$; by hypothesis each $X_y$ is compact, so there is a finite subset $\mathscr{U}_y$ of $\mathscr{U}$ that covers $X_y$. Let $V_y=\bigcup\mathscr{U}_y$; clearly $X_y\subseteq V_y$. Use the fact that $f$ is closed to show that there is an open $W_y\subseteq Y$ such that $X_y\subseteq f^{-1}[W_y]\subseteq V_y$. $\mathscr{W}=\{W_y:y\in Y\}$ is then an open cover of $Y$, so it has a finite subcover $\mathscr{W}_0$. Use $\{f^{-1}[W]:W\in\mathscr{W}_0\}$ and the appropriate collections $\mathscr{U}_y$ to find a finite subcover of $\mathscr{U}$.

Comment: Oh Very good example, thanks! I appreciate your help :D , but I'm still stuck with this problem xD At least I know that I have to use that hypothesis

Comment: @Miguel: I’ve added a bit to point you firmly in the right direction while still leaving some work for you.

Comment: http://at.yorku.ca/p/a/c/a/11.aim/ has my write-up why a covering map finite fibres is a closed map (and hence perfect). You can see I do use the covering property.

Comment: @Miguel: You’re welcome.